# What is the "application tape" mentioned in the EasyHeat installation instructions?

Tags: plumbing, freezing

The instructions that came with my "EasyHeat" water pipe freeze tape say to install it with "application tape" or good quality electrical tape.  I have electrical tape, so plan to use that, but have never heard of "application tape".  What is it, and what is it used for (other than installing freeze tape, that is)?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's a particular product available, but I think that it's also a generic term for any tape that meets their criteria. From the [instruction sheet](http://www.emersonindustrial.com/en-us/documentcenter/EGSElectricalGroup/products_documents/heating_cables/residential_heating_cables/residential_pipe_tracing/freeze_free_cable_plugs/14047_001_r12_FF_ii_web_low_res.pdf):

> Application tape (Cat.No. HCA) or high quality electrician’s
>   tape such as Scotch 44 or 33.

And...

> Only use ½" or 1" vinyl or fiberglass tape to attach cable to pipe

Of course, most readily-available electrician's tape is about 3/4" wide, but I imagine that would work fine.